# Unexplicable ambiguous interface

Tags: fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran, fortran95

If I overload the constructor of a given type as in the following example,
I get an ambigous interface. 
Since I have clearly different types in the interface, I don't get, why it should be ambiguous.

I know that I have the same names in the arguments, and that this can be a problem, if I want to dispatch with same types of different order, but this should not be a problem in my case.

```
module second_quantisation
    implicit none
    private
    public :: SingleExc_t, SpinOrbIdx_t

    !> We assume that Spin orbital indices are => 1, so set it to smth. arbitrary negative.
    type :: SpinOrbIdx_t
        integer :: val = -20
    end type

    type(SpinOrbIdx_t), parameter :: UNKNOWN = SpinOrbIdx_t()

    !> Denotes an excitation from src -> tgt as [src, tgt]
    type :: SingleExc_t
        type(SpinOrbIdx_t) :: val(2, 1)
    end type

    type(SingleExc_t) :: exc

    interface SingleExc_t
        module procedure from_integer, from_SpinOrbIdx_t
    end interface

    contains

    pure function from_integer(src, tgt) result(res)
        integer, intent(in), optional :: src, tgt
        type(SingleExc_t) :: res
        if (present(src)) res%val(1, 1)%val = src
        if (present(tgt)) res%val(2, 1)%val = tgt
    end function


    pure function from_SpinOrbIdx_t(src, tgt) result(res)
        type(SpinOrbIdx_t), intent(in), optional :: src, tgt
        type(SingleExc_t) :: res
        if (present(src)) res%val(1, 1) = src
        if (present(tgt)) res%val(2, 1) = tgt
    end function
end module




program test_ambiguous_interface
    use second_quantisation, only: SingleExc_t, SpinOrbIdx_t
    implicit none


    write(*, *) exc

    write(*, *) SingleExc_t(1, 2)
    write(*, *) SingleExc_t(SpinOrbIdx_t(1), SpinOrbIdx_t(2))
end program
```

Comment: The optional means that they are not clearly distinguishable. Consider the case where you omit both actual arguments

Comment: Of course. My bad, Thank you.